# Derived Attribute of average of another table

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to create a column in a table that derives its values from the average of the values of a column of another table.
I'd like to have the rating column in the table Series have the averages of the opinion column of the table Status where the name are the same.
This is the current database.

````
CREATE TABLE User
    (UName VARCHAR(30),
    Password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Score INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(UName));```

CREATE TABLE Status
    (UName VARCHAR(30),
    SName VARCHAR(50),
    Opinion INT,
    CONSTRAINT OpinionCk CHECK (Opinion BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
    PRIMARY KEY(UName, Sname),
    FOREIGN KEY(UName) REFERENCES User(UName) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON  DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (SName) REFERENCES Serie(SName) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON    DELETE CASCADE);

/* here comes the part where i have the problem:*/

CREATE TABLE Series
    (SName VARCHAR(50),
    Rating REAL AS (
        (SELECT AVG(Opinion)
        FROM Status
        WHERE
        Status.SName = Series.SName)
    ),
    Genre VARCHAR(50),
    Episodecount INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(SName));
````

Is there a better way to create the table Series? Maybe as a view...?

Comment: What's wrong with a query?

Comment: Other than typos (serie != series), what's the problem you face?